# how to get a php array generated from database into ajax variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have five questions coming from the database.  I need to store all the questions; each with its options and correct answer as a single array.  But the script below stores each question with its options as a single array - I have 5 arrays instead of 1.
What's the best way to achieve this; what modification can I make to the script please?

question.js

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "data.php", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
            var question_text = data[a].question_text;
            var choice1 = data[a].choice1;
            var choice2 = data[a].choice2;
            var choice3 = data[a].choice3;
            var choice4 = data[a].choice4;
            var answer = data[a].correctchoice;
    (function () {
        var questions = [{
                question: question_text,
                choices: [choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4]
            }];
             var   correctAnswer = answer;

             console.log('question: ' +  question_text, 'a: ' + choice1, 'b: ' + choice2, 'c: ' + choice3, 'd: ' + choice4, 'answer: ' + correctAnswer);
```

Comment: Welcome, new contributor John Olayiwola! Nice detail in your question. Are you asking for someone to write the ajax call (I do not see one here)? The general answer to your question is if you end your php with something that does an echo of a json_encode of your $row, then on the receiving end, in JavaScript, you can use parse the whole json string and have what you want. That'd be with something like const jsrows = JSON.parse(returnvalfromajax); (and then use it as you would any JS var)

Comment: oh....Thank you @Yishmeray. I really appreciate

Comment: Hi @Yishmeray. I have edited the codes based on your advice and can now get the questions from the database. But some new challenges came up which i have highlighted in the edited code. Kindly help out. Thanks

Comment: You're attaching click handlers to the `<div>`, not the `<a>`. I would suggest putting your IDs like `next`, `prev` and `start` on the `<a>` elements instead. Alternately, use `<button>` elements instead of `<div><a>Text</a></div>`

Comment: Thank you for your response @Phil. But I think the problem is that each of my questions and options are  stored as single array-so I have 5 different arrays for 5 questions instead of 5 questions in one array. I need help to store all my questions and options as a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the `questions` array on the outer scope and then push each question inside the `for` loop:

```
// Define an outer scope array here so you can use it later
var questions = [];

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "data.php", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
      var question_text = data[a].question_text;
      var choice1 = data[a].choice1;
      var choice2 = data[a].choice2;
      var choice3 = data[a].choice3;
      var choice4 = data[a].choice4;
      var answer = data[a].correctchoice;

      // Push a new question to the questions array
      questions.push({
        question: question_text,
        choices: [choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4],
        correctAnswer: answer
      });
    }

    // You'll have the array filled with each item to one question with all the options and the correctAnswer
    console.log('questions', questions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This is it @Christos Lytras. Thank you so much. It is working really fine.